# How to select an id from div generated dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get id from divs generated dynamically:

html:

```
<div id="resultats_son_div">
    <input type="text" name="titre_son" size="20" maxlenght="255" id="titre_son" class="texte_titre_son" placeholder="Titre du morceau">
    <div class="resultats_son" id="resultats_son">

<div class="titre_morceau" id="titre_morceau"><span style="display:none;" id="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/67232803">http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/67232803</span><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="lien_son" id="lien_son">Ed Sheeran - Give Me Love</a></div>
<div class="titre_morceau" id="titre_morceau"><span style="display:none;" id="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/9930614">http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/9930614</span><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="lien_son" id="lien_son">Ellie Goulding - Lights (Bassnectar Remix)</a></div>
<div class="titre_morceau" id="titre_morceau"><span style="display:none;" id="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/91141832">http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/91141832</span><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="lien_son" id="lien_son">Empire Of The Sun - Alive (Zedd Remix)</a></div>
....
....

</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to get id of spans generated when cliked on (I need them to generate a new div with content linked to this id).

My jquery to generate them:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#titre_son").keyup(function(e){
       var q = $("#titre_son").val();
       $.getJSON("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?callback=?", {
           q: q,
           client_id: "4346c8125f4f5c40ad666bacd8e96498",
           limit: "10"
       },
       function(data) {
           $("#resultats_son").empty();
           $.each(data, function(i,item){
            var str = item.title;
            var str_clean=str.replace(/'/g,"\'");
               $("#resultats_son").append("<div class='titre_morceau' id='titre_morceau'><span style='display:none;' id='" + item.uri + "'>" + item.uri + "</span><a href='#' onclick='return false;' class='lien_son' id='lien_son'>" + str_clean + "</a></div>");
           });
       });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#resultats_son_div').show();
    $('#player_son_div').hide();
    $('#player_son').hide();
    $('#resultats_son').click(function(){
        $('#resultats_son_div').hide();
        $('#player_son_div').show();
        $('#player_son').html("<iframe class='iframe' width='445' height='166' scrolling='no' frameborder='no' src='https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=" + $(this).find('span').html() + "&amp;auto_play=false&amp;auto_advance=false&amp;buying=true&amp;liking=false&amp;download=true&amp;sharing=true&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_playcount=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;start_track=0&amp;callback=true'></iframe>").show(); //Show second div on click event
        return false;
    });
});
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: As an aside, your current markup is invalid: `id` should be unique.

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.titre_morceau', function(){ //Your Code });`

Comment: `$('.titre_morceau').find('span').each(function() { code });` this you mean?

Comment: Can't see... :-( I need to get the span id when resultats_son (containing dynamic span generated) is clicked : $('#resultats_son').click(function()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `event` parameter to your handler function, and then use `event.target` to get the `<a>` element that was clicked. From there you can go up to the parent `<div>` and back down to the `<span>`.

```
$('#resultats_son').click(function(event){
    var spanId = $(event.target).parent('div').children('span').attr('id');

    $('#resultats_son_div').hide();
    $('#player_son_div').show();
    $('#player_son').html("<iframe ...></iframe>").show(); //Show second div on click event
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use classes instead of ids. When you don't have unique ids the behaviour of the query is not predictable.

Comment: I've changed to <div class="titre_morceau" id="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/9930614"><span style="display:none;" id="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/9930614">http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/9930614</span><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="lien_son" id="lien_son">Ellie Goulding - Lights (Bassnectar Remix)</a></div>

But I can't see how to get this id when parent is clicked...